# Orthographic projection

Tags: quadrilateral

> A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is given, $AD=BC$. The projections of $AD$ and $BC$ on $AC$ are equal. Is $ABCD$ parallelogram?

Let $DD_1\perp AC$ and $BB_1\perp AC$. We have $AD_1=CB_1$. I found that the triangles $\triangle AD_{1}D$ and $\triangle BB_{1}C$ are congruent. Does this help and how?

Comment: Why not an [isosceles trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid)?

Comment: $AD \parallel BC$